# Fontawesome styled icons doesen't work in vite.js

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, vite

Fontawesome styled icons does not work in vite.js. You may simply create a vite app then add fontawesome to it and you'll notice it.

The error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at node_modules/path-parse/index.js (index.js:3:17)
    at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=f1e39289:18:50)
    at node_modules/resolve/lib/node-modules-paths.js (node-modules-paths.js:2:27)
    at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=f1e39289:18:50)
    at node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js (async.js:5:24)
    at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=f1e39289:18:50)
    at node_modules/resolve/index.js (index.js:1:13)
    at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=f1e39289:18:50)
    at node_modules/babel-plugin-macros/dist/index.js (index.js:5:17)
    at __require2 (chunk-S5KM4IGW.js?v=f1e39289:18:50)
```

App.jsx:

```
import "./App.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  solid,
  regular,
  brands,
  icon,
} from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/import.macro";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={solid("user-secret")} />
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={regular("coffee")} />
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon({ name: "coffee", style: "solid" })} />
      <FontAwesomeIcon ic on={brands("twitter")} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Fontawesome doc about this topic: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons

Comment: Vite doesn't expose `process` and also there is special plugin for [babel macros in Vite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-babel-macros).

Comment: I installed it. now it says : babel-plugin-macros.config.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename babel-plugin-macros.config.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in C:\Users\mrkil\OneDrive\Desktop\test\package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).

Comment: code in babel-plugin-macros.config.js: module.exports = {
  "fontawesome-svg-core": {
    license: "free",
  },
};

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can see here, you are using React, so you can actually just:

```
npm i @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Choose the icons that you want, solid, brands, etc... :

```
npm i @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

Then:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faUserSecret } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faGithub } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";

...
 <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserSecret} />
 <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGithub} />
...
```

You don't need to do anything else besides install the packages and use just like I did above.

*Obs.:  check in which styles are the icons that you need, if they are in "solid" then add the free-solid-svg-icons package, if they are in brands, then add the free-brands-svg-icons package... you can actually do a search and find what fits best for you, cheers.*

Answer (score 4):

FontAwesome Macros are Babel Macros, so Vite needs a plugin to recognize and run them.

**1**
Install `vite-plugin-babel-macros` plugin:

```bash
npm install --save-dev vite-plugin-babel-macros
```

**2**
Go to `vite.config.js` and add the following:

```
import macrosPlugin from "vite-plugin-babel-macros";
...

export default defineConfig({
 ...
 plugins: [..., macrosPlugin()],
 ...
})
```

**3**
Add babel macros config file:

**create** a `.babel-plugin-macrosrc` file, with this content:

```
{
  "fontawesome-svg-core": {
    "license": "free"
  }
}
```

**IMPORTANT**

Vite project is created with option `"type": "module"` inside `package.json`, which makes `babel-plugin-macros.config.js` unable to use `module.exports`.

So instead of using a `js` config file, use an `rc` or `json` file.
If you changed your project type in `package.json` to `commonjs` just to make this plugin work, revert the change; it causes more harm than good.

You can read more about the config file for `babel-plugin-macros` in the [docs](https://github.com/kentcdodds/babel-plugin-macros/blob/main/other/docs/user.md#config), and choose any option you prefer other than `.config.js`.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but it worked great. Just had to change the npm command to npm install vite-plugin-babel-macros --save-dev to make it work.

Comment: @Andy glad it helped. it's a typo, I got it fixed.

Answer (score 3):

npm install --dev vite-plugin-babel-macros

vite.config.js:

```
...
import macrosPlugin from "vite-plugin-babel-macros"
...
export default defineConfig({
 plugins: [react(), macrosPlugin()],
})
```

in babel-plugin-macros.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  'fontawesome-svg-core': {
    'license': 'free'
  }
}
```

the missing link is package.json replace type "module" with "commonjs"

```
 -- "type": "module"
 ++ "type": "commonjs"
```